# React-Router does not redirect me from a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

and I have been working on a login project, and I used react-router to give routes to my pages, I make a button with  from a component to redirect me to the registry, but it only changes the route but the The interface does not change, it remains the same, and the only way to change it is by updating the page or using the  tag, but that makes the page update.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Code:

```
    import logo from './logo.svg';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

import ContainerRegister from './components/containerRegister'
import ContainerLogin from './components/containerLogin'




class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://192.168.1.7:3001/api/test')
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(console.log)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
      <div>
          <Switch>

          <Route exact path="/login">
          <ContainerLogin />
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/register">
          <ContainerRegister />
          </Route>

          </Switch>
        
      </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}


export default App;
```

Login component code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from "react-router-dom";

export default class containerLogin extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container container-login p-0 mt-5">
                <div className="barra-top p-1 d-blck"></div>
                <div className="text-center">
                    <h4 className="p-4">Account Login</h4>

                    <form action="" className="p-3">

                        <div class="input-field input-form col s6 pb-5 m-auto">
                            <input id="email-login" type="email" class="validate" classname="w-100" />
                            <label for="email-login">Email</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field input-form col s6  m-auto pb-5">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="validate" classname="w-100" />
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                        </div>

                        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
                            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                        </button>


                    </form>
                    <p className="pb-4">
                    <Router>
                        <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
                        </Router>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div >
        )
    }
}
```

I press the  tag But it only changes the path but the interface does not

Comment: Don't wrap your link in Router. By doing this you have changed the router context that the link is effecting. If you remove the Router surrounding your link the link should then correctly effect the higher up Router which is controlling the routes.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

It appears you've nested an additional `Router` in your `ContainerLogin` component. The `Link` is updating the routing context of the nearest `Router`. The `Router` wrapping the app and handling the other routes isn't "notified" of the change.

## Solution

Remove the extra `Router` in the `ContainerLogin` component. The `Link` will still work since it is still wrapped by the router context in `App`.

```
export default class containerLogin extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container container-login p-0 mt-5">
        <div className="barra-top p-1 d-blck"></div>
        <div className="text-center">
          ...

          <p className="pb-4">
            <Link to="/register">Register</Link> // <-- no router, just link
          </p>
        </div>
      </div >
    )
  }
}
```